# No Sound In Parse Push with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using swift with Xcode 7.1 iOS 9.1 and I have recently noticed that when I send a push notification either from parse.com, or client (within my app), it makes no noise here is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

let kREACHABLEWITHWIFI = "ReachableWithWIFI"
let kNOTREACHABLE = "NotReachable"
let kREACHABLEWITHWWAN = "ReachableWithWWAN"

var reachability: Reachability?
var reachabilityStatus = kREACHABLEWITHWIFI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
var internetReach: Reachability?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Parse.setApplicationId("A30cE46XOKXwA0EaGVKzEvQ2dmt1TZQo0DaykiRb", clientKey: "isuJsPBVcHFSBSTmTCnWOG6os0RzTME2QCQEHvP3")

    //Setup Push Notifications



    //let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    //let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    //Setup Push Notifications

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    internetReach = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    internetReach?.startNotifier()

    if (internetReach != nil) {

        self.statusChangedWithReachability(internetReach!)

    }




    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let currentInstallation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.save()

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

    print(error.localizedDescription)

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

}

func reachabilityChanged(notification: NSNotification){

    print("Reachability Status Changed...")
    reachability = notification.object as? Reachability
    self.statusChangedWithReachability(reachability!)

}

func statusChangedWithReachability(currentReachabilityStaus: Reachability){

    var networkStatus: NetworkStatus = currentReachabilityStaus.currentReachabilityStatus()
    var statusString: String = ""

    print("Status Value: \(networkStatus.rawValue)")

    if(networkStatus.rawValue == NotReachable.rawValue){

        print("Network Not Reachable...")
        reachabilityStatus = kNOTREACHABLE

    }

    else if(networkStatus.rawValue == ReachableViaWiFi.rawValue){

        print("Network Reachable via WIFI")
        reachabilityStatus = kREACHABLEWITHWIFI

    }

    else if(networkStatus.rawValue == ReachableViaWWAN.rawValue){

        print("Network Reachable via Provider")
        reachabilityStatus = kREACHABLEWITHWWAN

    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NetworkStatusChanged", object: nil)


}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.





    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    //self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.RandomDevelopment.Second_Reformed_Church_Mobile_App" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Second_Reformed_Church_Mobile_App", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Second_Reformed_Church_Mobile_App.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do{

    //if try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil){

        if (try coordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil) != nil){

        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        //error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dic as [NSObject : AnyObject]t)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
    }

    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    /*if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        //if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {

        do{

        if try moc.hasChanges && moc.save(){

            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        }catch{

            print(error)

        }
    }*/

    if managedObjectContext!.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext!.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also here is some code where i'm trying to send out client notifications:

```
@IBAction func sendPush(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let data = [

        "sounds" : "72128__kizilsungur__sweetalertsound4-2.wav"

    ]

    do{

    let push = PFPush()
    push.setChannel("Members")
    push.setData(data)
    push.setMessage(notificationTextField.text)
    try push.sendPush()

    }catch{
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo seems to be the problem assuming `72128__kizilsungur__sweetalertsound4-2.wav` is included as an asset in your project correctly. Change `"sounds" : ...` to `"sound" : ...`

```
let data = [

    "sounds" : "72128__kizilsungur__sweetalertsound4-2.wav"

]
```

should be

```
let data = [

    "sound" : "72128__kizilsungur__sweetalertsound4-2.wav"

]
```